# How to add Pagination to a Hugo theme

Tags: hugo

I am using Hugo (https://gohugo.io/) with the PaperMod theme (https://github.com/adityatelange/hugo-PaperMod).

Now I created a page where I want to post pictures. But the page will be very big after some month. So thats why I want to add pagination. There should be only 5 or 10 pictures per page. At the bottom the user can click through the other pages.

How can I do this? I'm a noob in editing templates so I do not understand how to follow the docs: https://gohugo.io/templates/pagination/

Maybe someone can help and tell me what I need to edit?

Page: https://i.ibb.co/1QzyRm9/ed6ebc2c5f3b83eed63ac93cfd7b8763.png

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

That theme seems to already use the [`Pagination`](https://gohugo.io/templates/pagination/) feature that Hugo has, so there is no need for you to change the template.

If you check the Hugo documentation on [configuring pagination](https://gohugo.io/templates/pagination/#configure-pagination), you'll see that there is a setting for the item count.

```ini
# config.toml
paginate = 10
```

You need to update your own `config.toml` file with this key, and set it to whatever you need, e.g. 5.

You can try changing the value, and creating some posts there, to double-check that it's working properly.